# Saving a custom Response using the Cache Storage API

Tags: caching, response, fetch, progressive-web-apps

I'm using [Cache Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) to build an progressive web app ( PWA ). There is a custom object that I need to [put](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put) into my cache, but the cache accepts [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) objects as an argument. So my question is how to properly create Response object, that has the JSON in it. I know I can use other caching strategies ( localStorage or IndexedDB ) but I'm particularly curious about this case - saving custom JSON in cache as a request.

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify({custom:"object"}); 
caches.open('cache-name').then(function (cache) {
  var response = new Response(); //My JSON should go into this Response obj. 
  return cache.put('cache-name', response);
});
```

Comment: Cache Storage is intended for usage in service workers. Your service worker would intercept a fetch request, find a match in its cache, and return the match if found. That's why the cache takes a `Response` object. Your question seems to attempt to use the cache as a general purpose store. Is that true? If so, don't use Cache Storage. Otherwise, if the cache is indeed intended for a service worker, your JSON response should be in a file (one that the client would request), and that file should be added to the cache upon installing the service worker.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I kind of try to use it as a general purpose storage - my idea is to modify the JSON and put it into the store. If the user have no internet connection, the service worker will return the modified JSON from the storage and the app would render with this, modified JSON. for now I use localStorage to save the modification and online-first strategy for caching with the service worker and it works fine. But I started to wonder, how would be possible to use the caches as a general storage for modified URL-addressable resources.

Answer (score 16):

Sure; it's possible to do that if it makes sense for your web app. You can do it wherever the Cache Storage API is supported, i.e. either in a service worker or from the context of a controlled page. Here's a basic example:

```
const data = {
  1: 2,
  3: 4
};

const jsonResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
});

caches.open('json-cache').then(cache => cache.put('/data.json', jsonResponse));
```

You can manually confirm that the data you expect is being stored via logging something like

```
caches.match('/data.json').then(r => r.json()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Almost the same example here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api#what_can_be_stored