# Is it possible to manually add to a service worker cache?

Tags: dart, service-worker

I am trying to make an interface that works with service worker but it currently expects to be able to write to the cache itself.

If it is not possible, it would be helpful to know if an expired cache resource will be used when network is unavailable.

**Edit** specifically  [Response](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/service_worker/latest/service_worker/Response-class.html) public constructors don't allow specifying the body data, and [Cache.put()](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/service_worker/latest/service_worker/Cache/put.html) requires a `Response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make an interface that works with service worker but it currently expects to be able to write to the cache itself.

The [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) is useful inside of a service worker, but it isn't limited to just the [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope). It's also [exposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/caches) on normal web pages as `window.caches`. So you can read from and write to the same caches from either your web page or your service worker (or a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), for that matter).

> If it is not possible, it would be helpful to know if an expired cache resource will be used when network is unavailable.

There's no concept of "expired cache resource" within the Cache Storage API. The `Cache-Control` headers in the cached `Response` are effectively ignored, if that's what you're asking about. So as long as a `Response` is stored in a cache, you can read it and make use of it. But nothing will be used automatically—you need to specifically set up a service worker's `fetch` event handler and add in logic that determines what happens in various scenarios. A good, generic overview of how to write that service worker code can be found in "[The Offline Cookbook](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/)".

For instance, [here's a `fetch` handler](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache) that will respond to all network requests by first going against the network (via `fetch()`) and if that rejects, tries to respond with a cached response for the same URL:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is quite helpful. When writing to the cache, a `Response` is needed but its public constructors don't allow passing in the cache entry's data.

Comment: You can create your own `Response` objects using whatever data in the body and headers you'd like. There's an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152270/385997